# Angular 5 unit test using new Date to check date

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a service function in Angular where it receives a date and check if the date is a date in the future. If it is, it returns true.

```
// The 'check_date' will always be in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`
public checkDate(check_date: string): boolean {
    const today: any = new Date();
    const dateParts: any = check_date.split('/');
    const dateObject: any = new Date(dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, dateParts[0]);

    if (dateObject.getTime() > today.getTime()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

How can I test this? Because if I do something like this:

```
it('should return true if date is in the future', () => {
    const date = '04/02/2018';
    const result = service.checkDate(date);
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Today it will pass, because `new Date()` will be `01/02/2018`. But if I run this test next month, it will not pass.

I could set the date to be test to be way further in the future, like `01/01/3018`. But I'd like to know if there is another method to test this case.

Comment: There's always [`new Date(8640000000000000)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093130/how-to-get-the-minimum-and-maximum-date) if you want to be *really sure* it never gets to the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Date` can be mocked to definitely test values it is supposed to return:

```
const UnmockedDate = Date;

spyOn(<any>window, 'Date').and.returnValues(
  new UnmockedDate('2018-01-01'),
  new UnmockedDate('2018-02-04')
);

const result = service.checkDate('04/02/2018');

expect(Date).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);

expect(Date.calls.all()[0].object instanceof UnmockedDate).toBe(true); // called with new
expect(Date.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([]);

expect(Date.calls.all()[1].object instanceof UnmockedDate).toBe(true);
expect(Date.calls.argsFor(1)).toEqual([...]);
...
```

Alternatively, Jasmine [Clock](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction#section-Mocking_the_Date) API can be used to mock date:

```
jasmine.clock().install();
jasmine.clock().mockDate('2018-01-01');

const result = service.checkDate('04/02/2018');

...

jasmine.clock().uninstall(); // better be performed in afterEach
```

Since `Date` is not a spy, the test won't be as strict as the one where `Date` calls can be asserted.

Comment: Do I need to import anything to use this? I'm getting lots of errors, such as `.all() does not exist`, and if I just `console.log(result)` it's always false, even when I change the dates to be as true. Ex.: `const date = '15/01/2018';  new UnmockedDate('2018-01-10'),` returns false. `const date = '05/01/2018';  new UnmockedDate('2018-01-10'),` returns true. If i invert the values of `new UnmockedDate()` it always return false. Any ideas?

Comment: Because I'm calling `New Date()` twice in my code (one using the result from the split method) I had to change to this code: `new UnmockedDate('2018-01-10'),  new UnmockedDate('2018-01-15)` in order to make the var dateObject as a valid date. Before it was invalid, since it was calling new UnmockedDate() with date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. But with this, it's not actually creating a dateObject from the function param, but from the UnmockedDate I'm setting last.

Comment: With this, even if I call `const result = service.checkDate('2014-04-10')` it will return true as long as I set `new UnmockedDate('2018-01-10'), new UnmockedDate('2018-01-15)`with the second date being in the future.

Comment: I have no ideas why `all()` may be a problem. [`.calls.all()` is there](https://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html#section-35) if you defined a spy, and `.calls` would be undefined if you didn't.  Yes, you may get rid of `date` constant because it isn't helpful, dd/mm/yyyy is valid for `Date` but the result will differ from `yyyy-mm-dd`. I don't know what the problem is because Jasmine-specific code I've posted is correct and workable. Consider providing a way to replicate the problem if it persists. Check [this testbed plunk template](http://plnkr.co/edit/3jh4Z6j2I7KPw9uAk9nE?p=preview)

Comment: Notice that `new Date('2018-02-04').getTime() !== new Date(2018, 1, 4).getTime()`. I don't think that it's the reason why it didn't work for you, but it may contribute to the problem. You may want to construct Date from yyyy-mm-dd string in checkDate for consistency. Tbh, Date is awful, and Moment or date-fns is the way to go in any real-world app where dates matter.

Comment: As for `all()`, there may be typing problems. Considering that you use Typescript (the question has JS tag but not TS), try to use `(<any>Date).calls...` instead of `Date.calls...` in all assertions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, but I found an alternative solution that nobody has mentioned when I faced a similar problem. I created a date by creating a today or now object, then adding days/years to it, depending on my needs.
For example:

```js
      const now = new Date()
      const yesterday = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate() - 1
      )
      expect(functionThatReturnsTrueForFuture(yesterday)).toBeFalse()
      const tomorrow = new Date(
        now.getFullYear(),
        now.getMonth(),
        now.getDate() + 1
      )
      expect(functionThatReturnsTrueForFuture(tomorrow)).toBeTrue()
```

This should work fine for situations in which you can pass the date you're comparing as a parameter (and has the benefit of not relying on any particular library).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at sinon fake timer:
http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.2.2/fake-timers/

```
describe('Date.now dependent test', () => {
   let clock; 

   before(() => {
       clock = sinon.useFakeTimers({
          now: 1483228800000
       });
   });

   after(() => {
       clock.restore();
   });

   it('test', () => {
       const now = Date.now();
       //now should always be 1483228800000 here
   });
})
```

It is based on https://github.com/sinonjs/lolex, which overrides native `Date` is a special way.

Comment: But the `new Date()` is not inside the test itself, it's on the service function I'm testing. This way I'll be creating a variable with a static time but only inside the `it()` method, not on the service.

Comment: But you are calling the service function inside `it`.
`const result = service.checkDate(date);`. Which means that you'll have the following sequence of calls: `before (where Date is faked)` -> `it (where you call your function and where the faked Date is used)` -> `after (where the faked Date is restored)`. So this method should work.

Comment: Why introduce extra dependency? Jasmine already supports this functionality https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction#section-Mocking_the_Date

Answer (score -1):

Usually I will just modify the input state for the SUT and call it a day:

```
let tomorrow = new Date().addDate(1);
let fnSpy = spyOn(service, 'funcToTest');
expect(fnSpy).toBe(true);
```

That should always ensure that the date being tested in the SUT is greater than the whatever "today" is at the time the test is ran.

Note: You may need to convert "tomorrow" to a string for your use case.

hope this helps.